# Setting Attributes within Angular Directives: Radio Button > set > checked = true

Tags: angularjs, set, directive, attr

EDIT PLUNKER EXAMPLE: http://plnkr.co/edit/WuiCAmMwbQnC0n197LSJ?p=preview
In the examples "sa" shoulbe checked and remain as checked. It is checked for a short time and then it looses its check status. I dont now why?

---

I am using a classical old fashion radio-button-based-navigation-tab-menu with Angular-UI-Router, it works well. Each click on a tab gets its URL.

If a user puts the URL manually into the adress bar of a browser and presses enter, the proper URL's content will be shown, it is also OK.

But my tab menu doesn't react on the manually changes at the adress bar. The correponding radio button should be checked. Therefore I've written a directive:

```
.directive ('checkIfMe', function (){
    return {
        link: function (scope, e, a) {
        ////////////////
            if (currentUrl == currentNaviElement) {
                console.log("Yes it is");
                a.$set("checked", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can detect the correct radio button, I see "yes it is" and I want to set its checked attribute to true. I've tried:

e.g. The ID of the current radio button is "navRadio_sa"

```
a.$set("checked", true);
a.checked = true;
$('#'+a.id+'').prop("checked",true);
```

All of them didn't work. But it I try it in the firebug console

```
$('#navRadio_sa').prop("checked",true);
```

it works. Where is my mistake?

Last but not least, that is a:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   .directive('checkIfMe', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, e, a) {
          scope.my.info.e.push(e);
          scope.my.info.a.push(a);

          console
          $timeout(function(){
            if(a.id == "navRadio_sa") {
              e.prop("checked", true);
              var me = (a.id).replace("navRadio_","");
            }            
          }, 10);

        }
    }

});
```

The e variable is a jQuery object of the element itself. You can work with it the same way that you'd normally work with jQuery objects.

I wrapped it in a timeout of 10 ms to give the ng-repeat time to complete before manipulating the dom. IT looks like ti was not working before because of a race condition. By setting the timeout, it should alleviate the issue.

Comment: No , unfortunately it does not work. That would be `e`: `Object[input#navRadio_{{item.service}}.naviRadio Eigenschafts Wert = "on" Attribut Wert = "null"]`

Comment: plnkr added, see my edit, thank you.. http://plnkr.co/edit/WuiCAmMwbQnC0n197LSJ?p=preview

Comment: In the examples "sa" shoulbe checked and remain as checked. It is checked for a short time and then it loose its check status. I dont now why?

Comment: It looks like there was a race condition. See my new answer.